# Populating react component results in "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to have a component populate with the results being returned from a GET request. The `PageList` component is below:

**PageList.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Page from './Page';

const PageList = props => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Your Pages:</h1>
            {props.pages.map(page => {
                return <Page page={page} key={page.id} />;
            })}
        </div>
    );
};
export default PageList
```

When loading the page with this component, I get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`. I imagine this is because the pages prop isn't correctly being passed to PageList from the actions and reducers? Not sure what I'm missing.

I'm mapping state to props in the following way in the container component that PageList sits in:

```
export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    {
        fetchPages,
        sendURL
    }
)(TestScraperFormContainer);
```

Here is the fetchPages action fxn:

```
export const fetchPages = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch({ type: FETCHING_PAGES });
        axios
            .get('*endpoint removed from post*', {
                headers: headers
            })
            .then(response => {
                dispatch({ type: PAGES_FETCHED, payload: response.data });
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
                dispatch({ type: PAGES_FETCH_ERROR });
            });
    };
};
```

and here is the respective reducer logic:

```
export const testScraperFormReducers = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCHING_PAGES:
            return { ...state, fetchingPages: true };
        case PAGES_FETCHED:
            return {
                ...state,
                pages: action.payload,
                fetchingPages: false,
                pagesFetched: true
            };
        case PAGES_FETCH_ERROR:
            return {
                ...state,
                error: 'Error fetching pages'
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you get when you print your response?

```
then(response => { console.log(response)}
```

Comment: `console.log('response:' + response)` prints out the following: `response:[object Object]`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you need to connect your reducer to ***PageList*** function because it doesn't know what is ***props.pages***.

You should try something like this:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    pages: state.pages
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PageList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably state.pages is undefined initially, because reducer initial state dont have pages set as [];

Setting `initialState = {pages: []}` in reducer might solve this;